# opencv2: VideoWriter - create virtual USB output

Tags: opencv, usb, virtual

Although opencv can easily read the input of a webcam, is there a way of creating a virtual webcam so that can be fed into a USB expecting program (such as skype, hangouts etc). The only docs for cv2.VideoWriter I found were here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter and that seems to be all filename driven.

Comment: no such thing exists atm, but i think, it's a nice idea !

Comment: @berak I feared that.... How do I get about putting it on the todo list ??

Comment: sure, you could make a [feature request](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues) - but i already  guess the answer: "hi there, cute idea, unfortunately our resources are limited. if you're able to code it , and make a pull request, we'll happily review it"